# Finding north without a compass

Tags: riddle, situation

At night, someone is in a completely empty field. He sees absolutely nothing around him and there are no stars in the sky. He does not have a compass, or any other tools that can be used for navigation, and the only think he knows about the time is that it's before midnight. He's been there for less than a minute, but he already knows which way is north.

How did he know?

Comment: Can he see the moon?

Comment: None of the answers there work, but a really interesting article on [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-True-North-Without-a-Compass)

Comment: "No stars in the sky"? This raises many issues, doesn't it? Can't he just not know which stars are which, like most people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Even though this answer got accepted: This answer will not really work and it is not 100% correct. Thanks to [Peter Taylor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/228/peter-taylor) and [Anachor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15544/anachor) for catching that. I would be interested if there is a better answer (there surely is).**

---

I'm just gonna post my answer...

> Becuase it's before midnight, the illuminated side of the moon faces west. (After midnight it's east). Now just face west and turn right - Then you face north.

Comment: You got it!​​​​

Comment: This can only work if the midnight in the question is geographic/astronomical rather than political. The politics of time zones cause midday in some places to be wildly different to the time when the sun is at its zenith.

Comment: And it doesn't work half the time, because of lunar phases. Because he is there only a minute, the moon isn't visible for half the lunar cycle.

Comment: Yes, so the answer to "How did he know?" would be "The moon was low enough in the sky to make any differences between the timezone and astronomical timezone insignificant, and the moon was visible."

Comment: @Runemoro Then, you have no valid reason to deny chasley's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Answer

> He is on the ice field at the South pole. Any direction is North.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the right answer, but good try!

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean an ice field.

Comment: That doesn't mean that I'm wrong. See this definition of ice field --->

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ice+field

Comment: Actually, you are. There is no light pollution at the south pole so he should  be able to see the stars. And there also is no "midnight", as there are no days.

Comment: 1. There may be a whiteout/blizzard that prevents him seeing the stars. 2. - "Some three months after the December solstice, around the March equinox, the sun will finally set at the South Pole and rise at the North Pole. Some six months after the December solstice, at the June solstice, it’ll be noon at the North Pole and midnight at the South Pole." ---> http://earthsky.org/earth/where-on-earth-does-noon-only-come-once-a-year-on-the-december-solstice

Comment: @chaslyfromUK How does he know he is at the south/north pole?

Comment: There is nothing in the question that says he is not at the pole. Therefore he could be. Clearly he is on an expedition there. Earlier he was able to know by other means precisely where he was. Knowing the *location* is not forbidden in the question - we are only asked about the *direction*. Presumably he could know *where* he was whatever field he was in.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yes, but what if he simply doesn't know where he is at, your answer is a creative one, but it is making too many assumptions.

Comment: It is also an assumption that you can see the moon. 1. It may not have risen or 2. If the stars are obscured so may the moon be, e.g. by heavy cloud. Incidentally does he know what hemisphere he is in?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Which is exactly why luxxminer has updated his answer to reflect that his answer does not always work, If this was a trick question, your answer would have fit perfectly.